# @nuxt/babel-preset-app > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended

Tags: babeljs, nuxt.js

I have an application which has core.js dependecy defined as **"core-js": "^3.19.1"** in package.json. But as I try to run yarn install it thorws me a warning

> @nuxt/babel-preset-app > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended

I dont understand how is it possible cause there is explicitely defined version 3.19

Can somebody explain me please what happened there and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you use also babel-cli? I had the same problem and it fixed when I removed babel-cli and installed @babel/cli instead.